# What time format is this, and how to get it from DatetimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to figure out what time format this is, and how I can get it from datetimepicker.

> 2013-10-28T18:17:00.000-0700

I've gotten this so far:

```
string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssssszzz");
```

but that just outputs this:

> 2013-10-30T11:28:53-07:00

Any ideas how I can get the output I'm looking for?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO8601

Comment: Thank you. Still trying to figure out how to get it out of Datetimepicker.

Comment: The problem you are trying to solve doesn't really have anything to do with DateTimePicker. It has everything to do with date format strings in general. DateTimePicker.Value simply returns a DateTime object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format your are looking for is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz`

Comment: More about Custom Date and Time Format Strings on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thats close. That gives me this:
2013-10-30T11:44:05.089-07:00

I need it without the colon in the timezone offset. But that gets me close enough I can google the rest. Thank you!

Comment: That lead me to this, which is the right answer. I'll accept your answer cause I couldnt have done it without ya :) dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzz00");

Comment: @Sugitime: `zz00` doesn't handle time zones that are offset by 30 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just need to add milliseconds (`.fff`) and remove the extra colon in the UTC offset:

```
string theDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz");
theDate = theDate.Remove(theDate.Length - 3, 1);
```

Note that `zzz` (unlike `zz00`) will properly handle time zones like Indian Standard Time, which is UTC+05:30.

Answer (score 0):

The `.Value` is a `DateTime`, so via the [Custom Format Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) we get

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz");
```

That is assuming the -0700 at the end is the timezone offset